# How can I represent a json array in an Environment Variable for aspnet vnext configuration

Tags: json, environment-variables, asp.net-core

I have the following section in my `appsettings.json` file for my aspnet vnext application.

```
"Settings": {
    "IgnoredServices" : ["ignore1", "ignore2"]
  }
}
```

This works quite happily in mapping using `IOptions<Settings>`, where the settings class is

```
public class Settings
{
    public List<string> IgnoredServices { get; set; } 
}
```

However, I am struggling to override this json file option with an environment variable form. I have tried

**Name**  `Settings:IgnoredServices`
**Value** `"ignore1", "ignore2"`

and

**Name**  `Settings:IgnoredServices`
**Value** `["ignore1", "ignore2"]`

Neither seem to map correctly and I get the following error message

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to convert '["ignore1", "ignore2"]' 
to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]
```

What format should I put my values into environment variables to be successfully interpreted as  the correct list of strings?

Comment: I'm also trying to store a JSON settings section in an Environment Variable. From what it seems, we can't. We have to individually create standalone variable for each settings and then pull those individually which yes is pretty clunky to me as well.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

**Name**  `Settings:IgnoredServices:0`

**Value** `ignore1`

**Name**  `Settings:IgnoredServices:1`

**Value** `ignore2`